# Unpause d3.timer

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm really new in d3, so maybe this question is too silly, but...
I want to create a globe, that rotate by itself and by user.
When user rotate the globe, it paused its own rotation, and after that resume it.

I tried to use mouse events, but it didn't work out.
So, I have smth like this:

```
timer = d3.timer(function() {
var dt = Date.now() - time;
projection.rotate([rotate[0] + velocity[0] * dt, 0]);
feature.attr("d", path);
});

//Drag
var drag = d3.drag().subject(function() {
    var r = projection.rotate();
    return {
  x: λ.invert(r[0]),
  y: φ.invert(r[1])
};


 }).on("drag", function() {
stopGlobe();
projection.rotate([λ(d3.event.x), φ(d3.event.y)]);
feature.attr("d", path);
});   

svg.call(drag);
```

Also, I heard about .off, but don't understand, how I can it use there. 
And I have this globe on codepen ->
https://codepen.io/bramsis/pen/QOPXej

Can you help me with this?

Comment: You want the world to return quickly when you click on it? or when you pull the mouse over the world, do you want it to be as if it was first opened?

Comment: I want the world continued rotation by itself, when I mouseup the world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a function start globe;

```
function startGlobe() {
      var r = projection.rotate()[0];//old state
      var k = projection.rotate()[1];//old state
      time = Date.now();
      timer.restart(function() {
        var dt = Date.now() - time;
        projection.rotate([r + velocity[0] * dt, k]);
        feature.attr("d", path);
      });
    }
```

On drag end call `startGlobe` function declared above.

```
.on("end", function () { 
        startGlobe();
      });
```

working code [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwVKeB?editors=0010)

Comment: Thanks! helped a lot!